# Symfony3 - Can I use assert "Count" on ManyToMany relation?

Tags: php, symfony, assert

I have an entity called `ActorSection` with a `Count()` assert on one field:

```
namespace ACME\ACMEBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ActorSection
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ACME\ACMEBundle\Entity\Post")
     * @ORM\joinTable(name="actor_section_post")
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = "1",
     *      minMessage = "Merci de sélectionner au moins un poste",
     * )
     */
    private $posts;

    //...
}
```

In my controller, both "add" and "edition" operations use the same script. The form validates even without selecting any of the "posts" children.

```
$handleRequest = $form->handleRequest($request);
if ($request->isMethod('POST')){
    if( ! $handleRequest->isValid()){
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('danger', "Error message");
    } else{
        $em->persist($Section);
        $em->flush();
        //...
    }
}
```

`ActorSelection` objects are saved just well, without any posts.
Does COUNT assert ignore manyToMany relations?

Edit: here's the relevant part of my form builder:

```
    $available_posts = $em->getRepository("ACMEBundle:Post")
        ->getAvailablePosts($convention);

    $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, $Section);
    $formBuilder
        ->add('posts',              EntityType::class, array(
            'label'  => false,
            'required' => true,
            'class'        => 'ACME\ACMEBundle\Entity\Post',
            'choice_label' => 'cinemaName',
            'multiple'     => true,
            'expanded'     => true,
            'choices'     => $available_posts,
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
```

Comment: Please you could show us the form builder sample where you're defined this field?

Comment: and "Yes" it works for `array` or `\Countable` instances.

Comment: @yceruto : I added the form builder code. It underlines the fact that i use an "outside" variable as choices value. But i do not see how this could affect Asserts on the final entity :/

Comment: Note: the $available_posts var is not in cause: Assert issue still happens if i comment this "choices" line.